# R skmeans package - where does this error come from: "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I tried to cluster my data in accordance with the manual provided by the [skmeans packages's manual page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skmeans/skmeans.pdf)

I started by installing all required packages.
I then imported my data table, and made a matrix out of it with:

```
x <- as.matrix(x)

# See dimensions
dim(x)
[1]  184 4000
```

When I try to hard partition my data into 5 clusters - as it is done in the manual's first example - like so:

```
hparty <- skmeans(x, 5, control = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Error in if (!all(row_norms(x) > 0)) stop("Zero rows are not allowed.") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

And when I just type:

```
test <- skmeans(x, 5)
```

I get:

```
Error in skmeans(x, 5) : Zero rows are not allowed.
```

I'm trying to figure out where this error is coming from, and why the function can't get a TRUE/FALSE value. Has anyone ever experienced this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you print out your rows and check that you do not have 0's. That is most likely your problem.

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for your answer! I just double checked, and I do have rows with 0's in them indeed. In fact, they are 0.000000's -because its a matrix of doubles. Is there a function to get rid of every single occurrence of 0.000000 in the entire matrix? (Sorry, total R beginner here)

Comment: well you should just remove rows with all zeros, do something like
X <- X[which(rowSums(X) > 0),]

Comment: Actually, now that I have tried to do the same with a different data set (again, 184 rows, 4000 columns, but other values), it just removed all rows except 3. It doesn't make sense because the matrix has most rows filled with values greater 0, just a few contained an actual 0. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Spherical means is k-means where every vector is normalized to length 1.

If you have a constant 0 vector, this is not possible, and you cannot use spherical k-means (or cosine similarity).

```
!all(row_norms(x) > 0))
```

is the test that you do not have a row of length 0.